# Two definitions for transverse $(p,p)$ form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

> Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n$ and let $V^*$ be its dual. Fix any integer $1\leq p\leq {n-1}.$ A $(p,p)$-form $\alpha\in\bigwedge^{p,p}V^*$ is said to be **strictly weakly positive** if for all linearly independent $\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_q\in V^*$, with $p+q=n$, the $(n,n)$-form
> $$\alpha\wedge i\tau_1\wedge\overline\tau_1\wedge\cdots\wedge i\tau_q\wedge\overline\tau_q$$
> is strictly positive.

Now, let $X$ be a complex manifold of dimension $n$.

Alessandrini--Bassanelli give the following definition in [Compact p-Kähler manifolds](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00181219):

> (Definition 1) A smooth $(p,p)$-form $\alpha$ is said to be **strictly weakly positive/transverse** if for every point $x\in X$, $\alpha(x)\in \bigwedge^{p,p}T_x^*X$ is a strictly weakly positive form on the holomorphic tangent space $T_x X$ to $X$ at $x$.

Similarly, we can also give the following definition:

> > (Definition 2) A smooth $(p,p)$-form $\alpha$ is said to be **"strictly weakly positive"** if for every (global) $\tau_i\in\Gamma(\bigwedge^{1,0}T^*X)$, $(1\leq i\leq q)$
> > $$\alpha\wedge i\tau_1\wedge\overline\tau_1\wedge\cdots\wedge i\tau_q\wedge\overline\tau_q$$
> > is  (global) strictly positive.

It seems to me that Definition 1 is more harsh than Definition 2, since not every form $\tau_x$ at the given point $x\in X$ can be extended to become a global $\tau$, right?
So, here is my question: are these two definitions equivalent? If not, could we provide an example to show that there exists some $\alpha$ is transverse in the sense of Definition 2 but fail to be transverse in another Definition?

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: You should not post the same question simultaneously here and on math stack exchange.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455541/two-definitions-for-transverse-p-p-form#comment1179421_455541), I don't find this question on MSE.  Am I missing it, or was it deleted?

Comment: @LSpice: I now cannot find it either. Maybe I was hallucinating...